# Prove the following series $\sum\limits_{s=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(sn)!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, exponential-sum

Prove that, $$\sum\limits_{s=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(sn)!}=\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{r=0}^{n-1}\exp\left(\cos\frac{2r\pi}{n}\right)\cos\left(\sin\frac{2r\pi}{n}\right)$$ 
I don't have a real idea on how to start approaching this question, some hints and suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Wow, this looks tough.  WHere did you get it?

Comment: the rhs equals $\frac{1}{2n}\Re\sum_{r=0}^{n-1}e^{e^{i 2 r \pi/n }}$

Comment: From an old A-level book from the UK, one of the few questions in the book I'm having trouble with.

Comment: the case $s=4$ is not difficult to prove

Comment: Yes, but I have to prove it for the general case.

Comment: take it easy step by step

Comment: ok $n=2^l$ also works

Comment: @tired you must mean $n=4$ since $s$ is a dummy argument.

Comment: @MarkFischler sure

Comment: Where can I get hold of that old A-level book?

Comment: And how do you prove this for $n=2^l$?

Comment: You can try ordering online from bookdepository, Further Pure Mathematics 2 and 3 (OCR), most of it is relatively easy. But there are a few miscellaneous questions that are quite hard. If you like difficult questions try searching STEP papers, these questions are specifically targetted at students looking to study mathematics in UK universities. http://www.physicsandmathstutor.com/step/

Comment: A partial result:

observing that 

$$
\sum_{s=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(4s)!}=\frac{1}2\sum_{s=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{(-1)^s}{(2s)!}+\frac{1}{(2s)!}\right)=\frac{\cosh(1)+\cos(1)}{2}
$$

which equals the rhs of OPs equation after some algebra. By the same scheme you may now tackle $n=8,16,32$ etc

Comment: For 
$$
\sum_{s=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^s}{(4s)!}
$$

play around with the real part of the series  

$$
\sum_{s=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{s/2}}{(2s)!}
$$

Comment: @tired, I see what you are doing, I'll attempt it further from here.

Comment: For what it's worth, the general name for this process is _series multisection_ and you can find more information about it under that name (e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_multisection ) - I first learned about this in Melzak's _Companion to Concrete Mathematics_.

Comment: I read Melzak's book many years ago and greatly enjoyed it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's $\sum\limits_{r=0}^{n-1} e^{i\frac{2\pi k}{n}r}=\frac{e^{i\frac{2\pi k}{n}n}-1}{e^{i\frac{2\pi k}{n}}-1}$ with $=0$ for $k\neq l\cdot n$ and $=n$ for $k=l\cdot n$, $l\in\mathbb{Z}$.

It follows $\sum\limits_{r=0}^{n-1} e^{e^{i\frac{2\pi}{n}r}}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{k!}\sum\limits_{r=0}^{n-1} e^{i\frac{2\pi k}{n}r}=n\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(nk)!}$ and therefore the claim.

Comment: i was so blind...also a big (+1)

Comment: @tired : Thanks! :-)

Comment: Thank you, I forgot I can go prove from the RHS.

Comment: @user51515 : You are welcome - it was a nice question. :-)

Comment: Note that $$\sum\limits_{r=0}^{n-1} e^{i\frac{2\pi k}{n}r}=\begin{cases} n&,k=\ell n\\\\0&,k\ne \ell n\end{cases}$$for integer $\ell$.

Comment: @Dr. MV : Thank you! (I have corrected - I have to be more precisely, I know :-))

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  -Mark

Answer (score 4):

$\newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> The roots of $\ds{z^{n} - 1 = 0}$ are given by
>   $\ds{\braces{\exp\pars{{2\pi r \over n}\,\ic}\ \mid\ r = 0,1,\ldots,n - 1}}$. Note that
>   $\ds{{1 \over n}\sum_{r = 0}^{n - 1}\exp\pars{{2\pi rs \over n}\,\ic}}$ is equal to $\ds{1}$ whenever $\ds{n \mid s}$ and it vanishes out otherwise.

\begin{align}
\color{#f00}{\sum_{s = 0}^{\infty}{1 \over \pars{sn}!}} & =
\sum_{s = 0}^{\infty}{1 \over s!}\,
\bracks{{1 \over n}\sum_{r = 0}^{n - 1}\exp\pars{{2\pi rs \over n}\,\ic}} =
{1 \over n}\sum_{r = 0}^{n - 1}\sum_{s = 0}^{\infty}{1 \over s!}\,
\bracks{\exp\pars{{2\pi r \over n}\,\ic}}^{s}
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over n}\sum_{r = 0}^{n - 1}\exp\pars{\exp\pars{{2\pi r \over n}\,\ic}} =
{1 \over n}\sum_{r = 0}^{n - 1}\exp\pars{\cos\pars{2\pi r \over n}}
\exp\pars{\ic\sin\pars{2\pi r \over n}}
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over n}\sum_{r = 0}^{n - 1}\exp\pars{\cos\pars{2\pi r \over n}}\bracks{%
\cos\pars{\sin\pars{2\pi r \over n}} + 
\sin\pars{\sin\pars{2\pi r \over n}}\ic}\label{1}\tag{1}
\end{align}

---

\begin{align}
\color{#f00}{\sum_{s = 0}^{\infty}{1 \over \pars{sn}!}} & =
\color{#f00}{{1 \over n}\sum_{r = 0}^{n - 1}\exp\pars{\cos\pars{2\pi r \over n}}
\cos\pars{\sin\pars{2\pi r \over n}}}
\end{align}

> It's clear that the *imaginary part* of \eqref{1} vanishes out.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this is also very helpful.

Comment: @user51515 You're welcome. It's nice it was helpful to you.

Comment: @FelixMarin: Nice elaboration! (+1)

Answer (score 0):

The expression on the left is the hypergeometric function with no upper and $n-1$ lower parameters of values 
$$
\frac1n, \frac2n \cdots \frac{n-1}{n}
$$
at value $z = n^{-n}$.

I don't know that his is very helpful:  The expression on the left has sorts of functions that are one-lower-index hypergeometrics (e.g., sin and cos) but it is not a simple convolution or anything.

Comment: I don't think the question involves anything on this level. But thanks for the help.