# Can multisection of $e^x$ be generalized to non-integer values?

Tags: power-series, exponential-function

This is a generalization of
[Prove the following series $\sum\limits_{s=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(sn)!}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1943975/prove-the-following-series-sum-limits-s-0-infty-frac1sn)
that I have no idea
how to solve.

Multisection of series
allows us to show that
$\sum\limits_{s=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(sn)!}
=\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{r=0}^{n-1}\exp\left(\cos\frac{2r\pi}{n}\right)\cos\left(\sin\frac{2r\pi}{n}\right)
$.

Is there a closed form for
$\sum\limits_{s=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(sn)!}
$
for non-integer $n$?

This would obviously
have to use the
Gamma function
and probably involve
integrals
(this last guess based
on just a feeling).

If this 
non-integral multisection
could be done for
$e^x$,
would it work for
general power series?

Inquiring minds want to know.

Note:
Doing a Google search for
"non-integral multisection"
does not turn up anything applicable.

Any ideas out there?

Comment: you mean for $s \in \mathbb{N}^*$ : $\sum_{n \ge 0} \frac{1}{(ns)!} = \sum_{n \ge 0}\frac{1}{n!} \frac{1}{s}\sum_{k=0}^{s-1} e^{2i \pi n k/s} = \frac{1}{s}\sum_{k=0}^{s-1} e^{e^{2i \pi nk/s}}$

Comment: and  $\Gamma(sn+1)$ instead of $(sn)!$ ?

Comment: No. I used the notation of the original question: s is the index of summation and n is the increment. The original question assumed that n was an integer, which leads to standard multisection. My question asks what happens if n is not an integer, such as 3/2 or pi.

Comment: Yes to the Gamma question.

Comment: ok but use $e^{2i \pi ks/n}$ not $\cos,\sin$. And I don't think there is a closed-form, because it leads to things of the kind $\int_a^\infty \frac{1}{\Gamma(nx+1)}dx$

Comment: The term "transseries" comes to mind ... There is an explanation/introduction online by Gerald Edgar (It is not that I knew how to actually do this problem, but transseries-concept seems to be pretty general and possibly expressive enough for such generalizations to fractional series-indexes)